# Is SbDrmServerCertificateUpdatedFunc properly implemented?

Tags: cobalt

Currently developing cobalt 19.lts.1.183273.
In this version, I confirmed that a new UpdateServerCertificate has been added.
I called the SbDrmServerCertificateUpdatedFunc callback function.

```
typedef void (*SbDrmServerCertificateUpdatedFunc)(SbDrmSystem drm_system,
                                                  void* context,
                                                  int ticket,
                                                  SbDrmStatus status,
                                                  const char* error_message);
```

but  In the drm_system.cc file,

```
  if (iter == ticket_to_server_certificate_updated_map_.end ()) {
     LOG (ERROR) << "Unknown ticket:" << ticket << ".";
     return;
   }
```

Returned from above.

I think the ticket value does not seem to be a problem.
what value should I pass?

thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pass the |ticket| parameter to SbDrmUpdateServerCertificate() back to the callback?

Comment: thank u for reply xiaoming.
Should SbDrmServerCertificateUpdatedFunc callback func be called from SbDrmUpdateServerCertificate ()?
However, SbDrmUpdateServerCertificate () was not called.

Comment: Yes, the current YouTube website doesn't call this function.  You have to send an implicit server certificate request to the server instead.  We have an internal implementation and I will try to include it in our next open source release.